# Code Review not for debugging or understanding -- Added to FAQ

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The Code Review Stack Exchange is for sharing working code from projects you are working on for peer review. As such, **I added a provision to the FAQ** that this site is *not* about debugging [or learning what code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-here).

**Please review the change below (in bold) and make sure this accurately portrays the intent of the site.**

From the FAQ:

> If you are looking for specific feedback about…
>
> - Code correctness
> - Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
> - Application UI
> - Security issues in a code snippet, etc.
>
> and your question is *not about* …
>
> - Tools, best practices, improving, or *conducting* code reviews
> - **Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets** ← *<sup><sub>(this is the added portion)</sub></sup>*
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> … then you are in the right place!

Comment: good call, working code is key

Answer (score 6):

Sounds good to me.

It isn't reasonable to do so, but I'd love for the "Make sure you include your code in your question" to be 10 times bigger and blink so people can't miss it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe emphasise the difference between "understanding code" (asker does not already know how it works/what it does - bad) and "making code understandable" (asker does know how it works/what it does but wants to make it clearer - good)